# Specify Library Target of Maven

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, gwt

How can I tell Maven to copy the dependencies into a specific location?

Side story: I am having a GWT project in Eclipse that is also a Maven Module for a larger project. This GWT project has dependencies to some libraries and I need them to be copied into `<project-dir>/war/WEB-INF/lib`. How can I tell Maven to do that?

---

**Edit**: I have found a way to copy a single dependency - but is there a way to copy all of them with a simple instruction?

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>junit</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I have also tried this:

```
</dependencies>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <!-- up to <phase>deploy</phase> -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Ending up with an error saying:

> Artifact has not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be executed after packaging: see MDEP-187.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to bend Maven to do things differently than what it expects you to do (e.g. here use `war` both as  input and output folder). As a rule of thumb, never try to fight with Maven, you'll lose eventually. Follow the (almost-undocumented) Maven Way™ or just use another, <strike>more</strike> flexible tool (such as Ant+Ivy or Gradle).

If you want to use GWT with Maven from within Eclipse with the Google Plugin for Eclipse, then have a look at https://web.archive.org/web/20130619170526/https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven and https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven

To answer your question directly, assuming a project with `<packaging>war</packaging>` where you'd have changed the `warSourceDirectory` from its `src/main/webapp` default to `war`, then try [`war:inplace`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/inplace-mojo.html).
The recommended approach though (see links above) is to use [`war:exploded`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html) (or [`war:war`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html), i.e. a simple `mvn package`) and run GWT DevMode using the `webappDirectory`, not `warSourceDirectory`.

Comment: Very good answer especially for someone new to Maven! It's good that I am at the beginning of setting up everything so I might chose another system - let's see how long I have to struggle with Maven. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If you want to use GWT with Maven, I recommend starting with my archetypes: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes If you want to learn more about Maven's design and its limitations, have a look at my blog (among many many others) http://blog.ltgt.net

Comment: Oh I see - The project wizard for a Maven Module in Eclipse lets me chose different archetypes but how could I install a new one? I think I have to read more about Maven. I'm still not sure if I like it..

Comment: Okay I see that this works but I'm not sure how to integrate these project with Eclipse ..

Comment: I generally launch my build tools (Ant or Maven or Gradle) from the command line; the only IDE integration I use is auto-configuration of the workspace/projects (and then the specific editors for e.g. JSNI or UiBinder). I don't "launch" projects from within Eclipse (not even with Run as… → Maven…, in part because of the way Eclipse hard-kills processes, leaving forked processes running and preventing cleanups through shutdown hooks).

Answer (score 0):

[`dependency:copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) should do the job.

Comment: I tried that one already but I ended up getting an error saying "*Artifact has not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be executed after packaging*"..